# Number of possible combinations of 10 numbers, 2 are fixed values and the others can vary from 0 to 9.

Tags: combinatorics

I have 10 values/variables:
$0 a b c d e f g h 9$

2 values are always fixed: 0 and 9, but the other 8 variables can vary from 0 to 9. Repetition is allowed and order is important. I want to know the total number of combinations I can have varying the variables and moving all the 10 values around in different orders.

Another way to phrase this would be: calculate all the variations with 10 numbers, which range from 0 to 9, but for a variation to be valid it must always have at least a 0 and a 9.

Examples of valid combinations would be:

$0900000000$

$9011111111$

$0123456789$

$0876543219$

$1230099321$
...

An attempt to calculate this:

- For the 8 variables I have a variation with repetition. The set of values they can take is $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. So I'll have:

$$VR_{10}^{8} = 10^8$$

- As the two other values are fixed to 0 and 9, I just want to see the different orders they can be in with the variations, so it will be a permutation of 10 values for every variation of 8 numbers possible:

$$P_{10}\cdot VR_{10}^{8} = 10! \cdot 10^8 = 3.6288 \cdot 10^{14}$$

Is this correct? Does it make sense?

Edit: thanks for the downvotes

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are you saying that this is an ordered $10-$ tuple?  That would make sense, except the $0$ and $9$ at the ends wouldn't mean anything.  Each unfixed position would have $10$ options, so $10^8$ ways to choose them.  But perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: 0 and 9 are there but they can be in any other position. I will edit my post to try to clarify it.

Comment: But how can we tell which $0,9$ were the original ones?  Your post is not clear. I suspect that if you were to write out the rules clearly, the computation would be similarly clear.  Why not edit your post to do a smaller case, like $[0\,a\,9]$ or $[0\,a\,b\,9]$?

Comment: To rephrase, you want to find the number of strings of decimal digits of length $10$ that include both $0$ and $9$.

Comment: If all you mean is that you want to count the ordered $10-$tuples of digits which contain at least one $0$ and one $9$, then Inclusion Exclusion is the way to go.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, that's exactly the idea 

Comment: You should edit your post to include your attempt.  How many decimal strings of length $10$ are there?  How many of these do not include a $0$?  How many of these do not include a $9$?  How many of these include neither a $0$ nor a $9$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Principle of Inclusion - Exclusion ?

Comment: Sometimes a key insight can be gleaned from tackling simplified versions of a problem.  E.g. suppose the string of values is only length three or four?  With the beginning and ending values fixed, the difficulty of counting possibilities is reduced and the pattern of solution might emerge.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I will read about the Principle of Inclusion - Exclusion, and I'll try to apply it to a reduced version of the problem.

Comment: @Hrvi downvotes don't mean "the question is too simple" but "the question is badly written"

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg yes I noticed, will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many decimal strings of length $10$ contain both a $0$ and a $9$?

If there were no restrictions, we would have $10$ choices for each of the ten positions, so we could form $10^{10}$ decimal strings of length $10$.

From these, we must subtract those strings which do not contain a $0$ or a $9$.

If a decimal string contains no zeros, we have just nine choices for each position, so there are $9^{10}$ decimal strings of length $10$ that do not contain a $0$.

By symmetry, there are also $9^{10}$ decimal strings of length $10$ that do not contain a $9$.

If we subtract $2 \cdot 9^{10}$ from the total, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted decimal strings that include neither a $0$ nor a $9$ twice, once when we subtracted decimal strings that do not include a $0$ and once when we subtracted decimal strings that do not include a $9$.  We only want to subtract these cases once, so we must add them to the total.

If both $0$ and $9$ are missing, then there are eight choices for each position, so there are $8^{10}$ decimal strings which contain neither a $0$ nor a $9$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of decimal strings of length $10$ that contain both a $0$ and a $9$ is
$$10^{10} - 2 \cdot 9^{10} + 8^{10}$$

Comment: Thank you so much ♥️. This is an amazingly good, clear and straight to the point answer. It has helped me to understand how the inclusion-exclusion principle works. I don't have enough reputation yet, but I promise I'll come back and upvote once I can.